# jquery submit() and clear the result?

Tags: jquery, osclass

I am working with osclass. Having problem with searching. I use a simple Jquery function. When I change my category it will gonna submit my query instantly. and it works. But this `search.php` will save this query. So, if I changed my category again, it gives me an error (there is no result). But again if I refresh this page, and change my category, then it works!

Here is my code :

```
$("#categ").change(function(){
    $("#formulario123").submit();
});
```

So, how can I clear this (html or query), while every time I change my category, before submitting search button?

Please, any suggestions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, your form i submittet to another target, which means that your category dropdown stays on the selected option. An now if you select the same option again the form is not submittet.
If that is what you mean, then the reason for this is that the change-event is not fired, because the dropdown is not changed, it stays on the same option.

Again if I understand you correct, you want to clear the dropdown selection after submit, correct?
One way of doing so could be like this:

```
$("#categ").change(function(){
    $("#formulario123").submit();
    $("#categ").val("");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick soluction. yes , this is dropdown option. this code is works. but i have a category which id is 'cat108'. so, when i select this category , 1st time its showing me no result. but again , if i select it again by using dropdown selection, then its shows me all result. why this happened with this particulur category??

Comment: I need more details on the HTML then, could you update you question with that detail (or create another question for that), then I'll be happy to se if I can help you on that. And maybe if you could create a JSFiddle on it, that would be really helpful, for the undstanding of your problem.

Comment: Hi, Ricki,, this is a php code. what i figure out.. there few category has various option. so,, if i change a category is called real estate, then relatet plugin is triggered and shows different option for searching like house type, made etc. and then if i back to change my category , then its shows no result. but second time changing same category its shows me all result. so,, problem is that, i need to clear all value which is comes from related category plugin and then submit.